# prevent values in form from passing

Tags: jquery, forms, webforms

I have 4 `<select></select>` elements in my form. Usually when submitting the form you would get this in the url, e.g.

```
index.html?day=01&month=01&year=1999&reporter=Joe+Blogs
```

However in my interface users are switching between the date picker and the person picker.
Is it possible to only send the values on the select that is active?

[I started writing this to post to you guys but then I had a thought and checked out the disabled attribute of form elements - so in the spirit of stack over flow I have entered my own answer too]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you disable this in javascript though?

You should make a server-side decision anyway, what if server gets the both person and date parameters (e.g. someone who has javascript disabled or just jquery blocked...)

Answer (score 1):

Use the .attr("disabled","disabled") in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the date picker and the name selection in separate forms (possibly with separate "Action=... 's).

Simple and works on any browser.

Answer (score 1):

yeah - after I did this I realised the problem I had created for non-js users. I have made a "todo" to break it up into two forms. I thought I was being smart by turning on and off different fieldsets (trying to use proper markup) but then, yeah, stuffed that up.
Oh well, least I learned about disabled and how to manipulate it in jQuery...

Answer (score 0):

I would rather prefer to pass the control to the server side for any sort of validation.